# How to combine two DataFrames in subplots?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I set a DataFrame like this.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
midterm = np.random.randint(0, 100, size = (1,5))
finals = np.random.randint(0, 100, size = (1,5))
print(midterm)
print(finals)
```

Next I made some codes.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(3, 1, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(3, 1, 2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(3, 1, 3)
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
width = 0.35

ax1.bar(labels, midterm, width, label='midterm')
ax.legend()
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.1)
plt.show()


ax2.bar(labels, finals, width, label='finals')
ax2.legend()
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.1)
plt.show()
```

My goal is combining ax1 with ax2 and printing in ax3, so I tried to do it.

```
ax3.bar(labels, midterm*0.4, width, label='midterm')
ax3.bar(labels, finals*0.6, width, bottom=midterm,
        label='finals')
ax3.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax3.set_title('Scores by each term')
ax3.legend()

plt.show()
```

But the result didn't come out. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Create your data as a *pandasonic* DataFrame:

```
midterm = np.random.randint(0, 100, size = 5)
finals = np.random.randint(0, 100, size = 5)
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
df = pd.DataFrame({'midterm': midterm, 'finals': finals}, index=labels)
```

Then, to print all 3 subplots, run:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(3, 1, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(3, 1, 2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(3, 1, 3)
width = 0.5
df.midterm.plot.bar(width=width, ax=ax1, rot=0, legend=True)
df.finals.plot.bar(width=width, ax=ax2, rot=0, legend=True)
df.plot.bar(width=width, stacked=True, ax=ax3, rot=0)
plt.show()
```

Note added *figsize*, otherwise all subplots have very small height.

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! By the way, I want to combine midterm multiplying 40% and finals multiplying 60%. Could you solve this problem?

Comment: Probably you should perform all miltiplications before you generate the printout.